# Non-bootable legacy Windows usb pendrive

Tags: windows-xp, bios, filesystems, bootable-media

I am trying to get some [vintage laboratory equipment](https://www.labwrench.com/thread/2197/tecan-user-manual) to work. Unfortunately out of my control; the laboratory equipment has software that is written for old Microsoft OS, like Windows XP. The software is allegedly able to provide control of the laboratory equipment. The Internet has given me a 64-bit Windows XP-image that I put on an empty [USB pendrive](https://www.x-kom.pl/p/126211-pendrive-pamiec-usb-kingston-64gb-datatraveler-100-g3-usb-30.html) with single partition on a fat32 file system using `dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4M`. I have also tried the [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) program. The people that tried the image on the Internet say it works great on their machine. However, my Bios says that `Boot failed: not a bootable disk`. How would I debug this problem? I have too little experience to say what tends to go wrong to cause such problems. So I have to ask people with more experience. The machine is [Thinkpad X230](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X230) with [Coreboot (seaBIOS)](https://github.com/merge/skulls) and GNU/Linux. According to Lenovo, the machine had official support for Windows XP (in the sense that there are drivers for the OS)

---

I get similar results whether I use a fat32, fat16 file system, whether there is a small partition or a single partition. I have tried to bit-by-bit write it to a block device without either a file system or partition table.

Comment: 1) writing that iso to an optical drive and booting from an optical drive is how XP was designed.  Even though you *can* put it on USB, this was the design. 2) That looks like a serial port on the back.. are you SURE it needs XP?  Serial I/O shouldn't need a specific device driver.  Only a COM port to plug it into.  I still have apps from Windows NT that work fine.

Comment: Windows XP 64-bit Edition was an entirely separate SKU from Windows XP.  Drivers had to be specifically created for it. Drivers for Windows XP were not compatible with Windows XP 64-bit Edition

Comment: Good catch @Ramhound.. I didn't even see that.  After you find yourself a 32bit copy of XP, you might even be able to install XP into a VM and install the software there.  The VM will need a pass-through COM port.  The "device driver" this product uses appears to be nothing more than serial IO through a standard com port.

Comment: I am not even sure Windows XP 64-bit Edition had the WoW32 compatibility layer, meaning, it only had the capacity to run 64-bit software. Needless to say it wasn’t widely supported.

Comment: Not familiar with old Windows ISO, but I think you need to prepare the drive with proper boot code in the MBR *and* in the boot sector of the *active* partition. Then you copy the *files* in the ISO to the drive. [ms-sys](https://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/) is a program that can help you with the first step in Linux. Unless the ISO has been specifically prepared for non-optical boot, pure "El Torito" ISOs are not expected to work when you simply dd it to a non-optical drive.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to create bootable USB drive with on Windows machine. Try using:

https://rufus.ie/en/

or

https://rufus.ie/en/

Comment: It won't make any difference.